# Converting a list of integers to strings using map()

Tags: python, dictionary, type-conversion

I dont understand why python is not allowing me to use the map() function to change a list of integers to a list of strings. When I try to do it in the python shell it works fine but not when I try it in a script, I am really confused to why this happens. Here is my code for the script:

```
def DashInsert(str):

    list_int = map(int, list(str))
    list_str = map(str, list_int)

    return list_str
```

Also I know that I dont need to change the list back into a string if it is already coming in as a string, but I am curious to why Python wont let me change the list after I turn it into a list of integers. I keep on getting the 'str object is not callable' error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do this:

```
def DashInsert(str):
```

You're shadowing the `str` builtin for the scope of `DashInsert`, so when you try to use `list_str = map(str, list_int)` it won't work as expected because `str` is no longer Python's builtin, it's equal to the object that you've passed as `str` to the function. Consider renaming it, eg:

```
def DashInsert(text):
    list_int = map(int, list(text))
    list_str = map(str, list_int)
    return list_str
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Would you be able to explain the shadowing concept a little more in detail?

Comment: @RidwanKazi Python's fairly flexible when it comes to assignments. So you could do `int = float`, then do `int(3)` and you'd get `float(3)` instead... A general rule of thumb is to avoid naming your own variables the same as Python's builtins...